# creating PHP site in IIS

Tags: php, iis

Can I create a PHP site with MySQL database in IIS?

Comment: Yes, yes, you can.

Comment: Who hasn't read their manual then?

Comment: it can be but i would not recommend to do so as there are certain things that require a lot of work to get working under iis which are very simple to achieve with apache. get wamp or xampp its free and easy.

Comment: It is my humble request that before posting questions, go for google first.....!!!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please see [this](http://php.iis.net/).

Comment: but IIS is already is instealled in my pc